# How deliberately stall fixed wing reduce drag if stall decrease static pressue?

Tags: aerodynamics, drag, stall

In this [VIDEO](https://youtu.be/Hs2zWYSqUfY?t=340) at 5:40 we can see how stall decrease pressure at upper wing surface.

If stall/flow separation reduce static pressure how in this [VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=125&v=nDIJdeR4AaU&feature=emb_logo&ab_channel=Autosport) they reduce drag when stalling the wing?

Here is description how works:
https://formula1techandart.wordpress.com/2010/12/14/mc-laren%E2%80%99s-innovative-rear-wing-system-f-duct/

https://www.formula1-dictionary.net/f_duct.html

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know about pressure, but stalling always **increases** drag.

Comment: This is not about aviation, voting to close.

Comment: Concepts are related to "blown flaps".  Let's work to understand it.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni, then edit the question and graphics to be about blown flaps on airplanes.  This site is about aviation, not automobiles.  (Race cars have tires, should we allow questions about race car tires because airplanes also have tires?)  You don't have to agree with me, but the vote stands.

Comment: @MichaelHall I see your point and respect your verdict, however, I find this question interesting as an aerodynamic optimization task. Also, I wonder whether a car site will be able to answer it well.

Comment: @PeterKämpf, and I agree with what you just said...  But, I believe Jurgen has a responsibility to establish a connection with aviation in order to make it relevant enough to keep open.

Comment: @MichaelHall I think question is great, it shows the beauty of aerodynamics at its best. Aerodynamics is basics of aviation and this question is 100%  about aerodynamics.

Comment: @JurgenM Aerodynamics is at the basics of aviation, but that does not mean that every aerodynamics question is fit for this site. Since this question is about a stalling airfoil, the aerodynamics could fit into the domain of aviation and be of interest to our community, but it is borderline.

Comment: Questions about aerodynamics are [off-topic here](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4151/should-we-allow-questions-which-are-likely-answerable-by-the-experts-here-but-a), unless they are related to aviation. As currently written, this question is exclusively about F1 technology. Why not rephrase it to something like **Could this F1 technology be used to reduce drag on aeroplanes?**

Answer (score 5):

As the linked site explains, this is not about aerodynamic drag of the flap but the whole drag of the vehicle.

F1 cars use rear wings to increase downforce so they can turn faster. The downforce of those wings increases the load on the tires and, consequently, the amount of side force they can tolerate before they skid. This allows to drive faster through turns.

This tire load, however, increases rolling resistance, so on straights it would be better to do without this downforce. In airplanes we use moveable flaps but the F1 cars have decided to vary flap lift by blowing air into the low-pressure side. This raises local pressure, reduces downforce and, consequently, rolling resistance so the car can drive faster.

In effect, by switching the air flow on in straights and blocking it in turns, the car can be optimized to both run faster on straights and run faster in turns without skidding.

Since the low-pressure side of the wing and flap is pointing backwards, increasing local pressure also should reduce the amount of aerodynamic drag there. But the main effect is to vary the lift this wing and flap produce and thus to vary downforce such that the car can reach higher speeds overall.

Stall in aeroplanes means drag goes up because lift needs to be produced and stalling makes this less efficient. Here, however, stall will greatly reduce lift - in cars there is no need to keep lift equal to weight! And reducing lift will also reduce drag, even though the L/D ratio might go down in the process.

Comment: If you close the slot between main wing and "flap wing",all rear wing will stall. Will you then increase drag and will you increase lift of rear wing compare when slot is open and flow is attached?

Comment: @JurgenM closing the slat will greatly increase drag and decrease downforce. While blowing into the low suction area reduces downforce, too, it causes drag to increase less because the additional air volume will raise pressure in the separated flow. Closing the slot is less helpful than blowing.

Comment: " While blowing into the low suction area reduces downforce, too, it causes drag to increase less "  You write in your answer that blowing air in low pressure side reduce aero drag of wing, not increase. ?

Comment: @JurgenM … relative to separation without blowing.

Comment: So when f duct is ON(blowing) aero drag of wing is lower then when f duct is OFF(attached flow)?

Comment: Yes, aero drag **and rolling drag** are lower, and so is downforce. Only the L/D of the wing is lower, so drag goes down less than downforce. Still better for speed than with blowing off.

Comment: "_Typically, wing stall is correlated with an increase in aerodynamic drag force. However, in the case of the finite wing with low aspect ratio, the induced drag is dominant and is proportional to the downforce. Therefore, flow separation on the wing increases the profile drag while simultaneously reducing the induced drag, resulting in a decrease in the total aerodynamic drag._"  https://journals.pan.pl/Content/84720/PDF/03_paper.pdf  stalled wing has lower drag even in case with just slot  closed...dont agree?

Comment: @user628075 Why shouldn't I agree? I still think that blowing air into the highest suction is more efficient, but closing the slot will also reduce lift.

Comment: yes blowing air is more effective then close the slot, but you write in comments that close the slot will increase drag..."before blowing teams used flexible wing sections which allowed the 'slot gap' to close up under high aerodynamic loads and stall the wing. Once this became evident to the governing bodies it was rapidly outlawed. Wings are now subject to static load tests to ensure that they cannot flex.
So if a team were able to achieve a similar effect within the regulations, considerable straight-line performance gains could be made."

Answer (score 2):

This is more race car - technical, but in [this](https://www.racecar-engineering.com/tech-explained/f-ducts-how-do-they-work-f1-2010-formula-one-technology/) reference they explain that **only the rear slotted portion of the airfoil is stalled, not the entire  (inverted) wing**.

Apparently, the reduction in downforce in straightaway results in an increase in speed.  This may be due to a variety of factors, such as the rear tires being "squished" or compressed less, reducing their friction and energy loss from deformation.

The claim is that the lift to drag ratio is reduced, but lift is reduced so much more that there is a net loss in drag.  This explanation may be somewhat dubious but apparently the device works.

A more suitable reason may be that the flap is angled in such a way that it's "lift" not only produces downward force, but also a significant amount of rearward force. When the "bleed slots" are activated by the driver, they simply reduce the flap lift *without* stalling it.

Comment: ,some teams blown air in main wing, some in second wing